# Apply CSS on button in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I started experimenting with MVC 3. And I'm stuck with applying the style of an input-button.

Is it possible to apply Css in the View? The code I gave is located in the View.

```
<input id="newSubItem" type="button" onclick="location.href='javascript:void(0);'" value='New Subitem' /><br/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try

```
 <input id="newSubItem" class="myCSSClass" type="button" onclick="location.href='javascript:void(0);'" value='New Subitem' />
```

Comment: I'm using jqModal and i need the class-attribute to close the jqModal dialog by setting the value of class to jqmClose.

Comment: Actually this is a separate question, can you please create another question for this. Because for this I will need to change my answer, and currently my answer solves your current question. Thanks

Comment: you can use this notation `$("#newSubItem").removeClass("myCSSClass").addClass("jqmClose");` once your jqModal closes.

Comment: Here is the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160386/how-to-close-jqmodal-dialog-without-setting-jqmclose-tag-in-class-attribute-of-a/9160702#9160702

Comment: As promised here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160386/how-to-close-jqmodal-dialog-without-setting-jqmclose-tag-in-class-attribute-of-a/9161154#9161154 :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put link in the view to your css page :

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/CSSPAGE.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And then you can apply any class you want,for example

```
<input id="newSubItem" class="CSSClass1" type="buttononclick="location.href='javascript:void(0);'" value='New Subitem' />
```