# Close jqModal dialog without setting jqmClose-tag in class-attribute of an input-button

Tags: javascript, jqmodal

I'm using jqModal in my ASP.net MVC 3 project. I have some buttons where I apply CSS-styling on them but I've read that the class attribute of an input element can be used to close jqModal-dialogs.

This is an example of a code where jqModal's jqmClose-function is defined in the class attribute of the input-element:

```
<input class="jqmClose" type="button" onclick="DeleteItem()" value='Bevestig' />
```

Is there another way to use the class-attribute for CSS-styling and close the jqModal-dialog without using jqmClose?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your input has _two_ class attributes.

Comment: That's right, I forgot to delete one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `jqmHide` method to close a dialog: `$('#my-dialog').jqmHide()`;

Also, your input has two class attributes.

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#how

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is **`closeClass`** - but this only works with images. When a dialog is shown, elements that have a CSS class of **`closeClass`** will close the dialog when clicked.

For instance; If your with your dialog you have put the following html inside:

```
<img class="closeClass" src="close.gif">
```

the dialog will close when that**image is clicked**.

You can use:

```
$(*'your-dialog-box-selector-here'*).jqmHide()
```

to close a dialog manually. i.e. if your div's id is "jqmodal" you put `$("#jqmodal").jqmHide().`

But with the image with the class closeClass above within the div, you don't have to program it manually.

Hope this answers your question.